# react displays raw json data after request to express server

Tags: json, reactjs, express, react-router

I want to configure my react js with backend with react-routes. But I've noticed that I get raw json after api request, which, I suppose can be very insecure.

One man posted here that:

"If your user navigates to the server route that is serving the RAW JSON, the browser will receive the JSON and display it without any templating, styling, or other page elements. Therefore, your server URLs and your client URLs need to be different, and your server should use URLs that are exclusively identified as API urls. many people prepend /api/ to these URLs to avoid confusion, or secure them so that clients can't request them directly."

So, my '/' path is localhost:3000, it renders 'Home' component which has Users and About components on localhost:3000/users and localhost:3000/about.
From each of these nested components I make a fetch request to 'api/users' and 'api/about' accordingly his advices. Everything works fine, but if I type in *localhost:3000/api/about* the browser displays raw json data. So how am I suppose to have different server URLS and client URLS without having this problem?

Index.js

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return(
      <div id="user">

        <Router>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about/">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/users/">Users</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about/" component={About} />
        <Route path="/users/" component={Users} />
      </Switch>
      </Router>

      </div>
    );
  }
```

About.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/about')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(msg => {
        console.log(msg);
        this.setState({msg}, () => console.log('React fetch: successful'))
      });
  }
```

server.js

```
const dir = path.join(__dirname, '../build');
app.use(express.static(dir));

app.get('/api/about', function(req, res) {
    const list = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Pizza",
        "price": "10",
        "quantity": "7"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Cerveja",
        "price": "12",
        "quantity": "5"
    }
];
     return res.json(list);
});

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: I think that the advice that you received was meant for you to divide your frontend app from you backend app. For example you could run the frontend app from localhost:3000 and the backend in localhost:5000.

Comment: I did so. My frontend app is running on localhost:3000, backen in localhost:8015

Comment: But if you did it, fetching: `localhost:3000/api/about` shouldn't return anything since your server is running on a different port.

Comment: It is because I use proxy on my webpack dev server, which redirect every request from localhost:3000(frontend webpack dev) to localhost:8015(express server).

Comment: In that case don't bother with that. Proxy is only used in development mode so, in production it won't happen. In case you just want to avoid this everywhere you can use an env var to set the api url.

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

that is what I usually do.

Comment: I have these problem in production as well=) 
I suppose I have to redirect all server requests to index.html which will download all the JS resources and allow React Router to take it from there somehow. The server should send index.html that would render react and make the request for the data by fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue has more to do with what kind of data is in that JSON. If it should not be shown then why pass it back to the front-end? You can really obfuscate what the api end points are but all the user has to do is to check the network calls in his browser to figure them out. You can also try to encrypt it but since the front-end would decrypt it it would just delay the inevitable. If you really want to secure the data to particular users then you must have a login and session handling mechanism.